# Programmatically close any open lightbox?

Tags: jquery, lightbox

How can I programmatically close any open lightbox ?

I need close the lightbox when the ajax request is finished, any way ?

Using [ekko-lightbox](https://github.com/ashleydw/lightbox/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fire off an event when the AJAX call completes, and have the lightbox listen for the event and close itself when it sees it.

```js
// When your AJAX call completes
var event = new CustomEvent('someEventOrSomething');
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

```js
// Your lightbox stuff
$(whateverYoureLightboxing).ekkoLightbox({
    onShown: function() {
        var lightbox = this;
        document.addEventListener('someEventOrSomething', function () {
            lightbox.close();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: this.close(); or lightbox.close(); ?